# How to format date in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, vba

Hello I'm using MS JET OLEDB 4.0 on VBA (MS ACCESS)

```
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(Date) FROM [Orders] WHERE [Orders].[Date] BETWEEN " & "#" & StartDate & "#" & " AND " & "#" & EndDate & "#"
```

The [Date] is formatted like f dd/mm/yyyy (French) and the StartDate and EndDate are formatted like mm/dd/yyyy (Two date objects).

My belief is that BETWEEN only compares dates formatted mm/dd/yyyy, so is there a way like a function to convert the [Date] formatting into mm/dd/yyyy so the between function can compare correctly?

Edit: Using a string instead of the dates like follow:

```
StartDateFormatted = Format(StartDate,"dd/mm/yyyy")
EndDateFormatted = Format(EndDate,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

So as to be sure of the startdate and enddate format. It doesn't work still.

I'm left to assume two things:

- Either BETWEEN onlys compares mm/dd/yyyy formats
- I have to use a function to format [Date] to mm/dd/yyyy

Thanks to @Maciej Los for answering my question.

Comment: Don't know if it helps but found a piece of doc about a convert function: i.e. Format (Now, “MM/dd/yyyy”) https://www.udemy.com/blog/vba-format-date/

Comment: :/ I read that a while ago!

Comment: However, since the columns should be date fields, the format shouldn't have any effect on the comparison, or am I wrong!? Is it possible that `[Orders].[Date]` is of another type (maybe a text)?

Comment: I would do a "select getDate()" and watch the format returned then use that format in the query. Another thing is that he formatting of the dates is a localization setting for the database.

Comment: Your belief is incorrect. Is the date column of type date is one question. The other is what's the locale of the server i.e. is it treating 08/05/2015 as the 8th of May or the 5th of August. If you want between to work properly it should be using dates, formatting is irrelevant.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, Formatting will do the job, if the date will be formated in ISO standard: MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: @MaciejLos, This is one of those just because you can doesn't mean you should things in my book.

Comment: So the RDBM system will compare dates whether mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy. It depends how it treats the input days? @TonyHopkinson

Comment: Sure it's assuming based on it's current locale. Change your settings and 5/8 is August. The format idea works as would using an unambiguous date format. Lost count of how many times I've seen people trip over this one '05/08/2005' is not a date, it's a string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Format function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php).

```
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(Date)" & vbcr & _
"FROM [Orders]" & vbcr & _
"WHERE [Orders].[Date] BETWEEN #Format(" & StartDate & "], 'MM/dd/yyyy')# AND #Format(" & EndDate & ",'MM/dd/yyyy')#"
```

Comment: I can't use that. VBA has " problems. Can you format it?

Comment: try `between #" & Format([StartDate], "MM/dd/yyyy") & "# AND #" & Format([EndDate], "MM/dd/yyyy") & "#"`

Answer (score 4):

Always use ISO date formatting YYYY-MM-DD and you will have no problems. Without formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed from the SQL compilation of the query when using Between, that it turns it to MM/DD/YYYY and it did not work till I used Format(startdate, "mm/dd/yyyy"). Please check the snapshop.

[image]