# How to change Ordinal Date to MMDDYYYY

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ibm-midrange

I have a SQL String that converts the Ordinal Date stored on the Server, but when I add the string to VBA I get the `Run Time Error that the Column or global variable doesn't exist`.

When I use the string in Microsoft Query it works just fine.  Please note I have almost no knowledge of SQL.

**This is the SQL String I am using to convert from YYYYDD to MMDDYYYY**
`decimal(replace(char(date(timestamp_format(digits(CFMAST.CFDOB7),'YYYYDDD')),usa),'/',''),8,0)`

**Here is how I am implementing it into VBA for Excel**

```
strSQL="SELECT decimal(replace(char(date(timestamp_format(digits(CFMAST.CFDOB7),'YYYYDDD')),usa),'/',''),8,0) FROM CNCTTP08.JHADAT842.CFMAST "

strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (CFMAST.CFDOB7<>0) AND (CFMAST.CFDOB7<>1800001)"
```

When I run the query through Microsoft Query I get the expected result where it formats all of the dates from `CFMAST.CFDOB7 as MMDDYYYY`, but when I run the string in `VBA` I get the following error:

> [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0206 - Column or
>   global variabl CFDOB7 not found.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819611/how-to-format-date-in-a-sql-query

Comment: Unfortunately, that post doesnt work for me because I am not using Access and I have very limited knowledge of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you are using a three part name for the table `CNCTTP08.JHADAT842.CFMAST`. Remove the system name `CNCTTP08` and just use the schema and table `JHADAT842.CFMAST`. Your ODBC connection should get you to the correct system.

Another issue may be that DB2 for i doesn't really like correlated names unless one has been explicitly defined. So if you really do need the three part name, add a correlation identifier in the `from` clause like this:

```
FROM CNCTTP08.JHADAT842.CFMAST AS CFMAST
```

Comment: This is what it was.  once I added the `AS CFMAST` it worked perfectly.

Comment: Would you be able to point me in the right direction to now convert `strSQL="SELECT decimal(replace(char(date(timestamp_format(digits(CFMAST.CFDOB7),'YYYYDDD')),usa),'/',''),8,0)` to Age in Years?

Comment: Best to ask a new question for that. Comments can go away, and then no one else can benefit from it. But you should already be able to find out how to find the numbers of years between dates somewhere on SO. BTW, you already have a date ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using an alias in your FROM clause, such as "FROM CNCTTP08.JHADAT842.CFMAST T01" and using T01 to replace the CFMAST"

```
strSQL="SELECT decimal(replace(char(date(timestamp_format(digits(T01.CFDOB7),'YYYYDDD')),usa),'/',''),8,0) FROM CNCTTP08.JHADAT842.CFMAST T01"

strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (T01.CFDOB7<>0) AND (T01.CFDOB7<>1800001)"
```

Let me know what you get.

Comment: I needed to add the `AS CFMAST` to the end of the `FROM`.  Thank you for looking at this.