# Error in Excel VBA with SQL query between two dates

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am using SQL inside an Excel Sheet using the following provider

```vb
Set m_Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

m_Connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                  "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

I have two textboxes (from and to) where users type two dates From, To, to select the records corresponding at this date selection

I am facing the following problems:

First of all I tried this code, I was getting all the fields whatever are the dates dates from the sheet, except if I have a blank sheet, the ones where the cells are empty inside the column date are empties, so I wasn't getting an error, but my condition between two dates doesn't work

```sql
SELECT [ListName] AS [List name] 
FROM [Database$] 
WHERE CDATE([ClipDate]) BETWEEN #01/09/2017# AND #14/03/2019#;
```

I tried not to use the `BETWEEN`, but I got same wrong results (all records except empty ones are selected whatever is the ClipDate)

```sql
SELECT [ListName] AS [List name] 
FROM [Database$] 
WHERE CDATE([ClipDate]) >= #01/09/2017# AND CDATE([ClipDate]) <= #14/03/2019#;
```

I tried the following one, by replacing the # by "", this time I get a good date selection (the ones that I want), but I get an error saying "Invalid Use of Null" if any of the cells at the column Date is empty.

```sql
SELECT [ListName] AS [List name] 
FROM [Database$] 
WHERE CDATE([ClipDate]) >= "01/09/2017" AND CDATE([ClipDate]) <= "14/03/2019";
```

I tried at the end this, and got the same result as previous one , Invalid Use of Null in case of blank cell

```sql
SELECT [ListName] AS [List name] 
FROM [Database$] 
WHERE CDATE([ClipDate]) BETWEEN "01/09/2017" AND "11/03/2019";
```

here is the screen of From, to

[image]

In my Excel sheet I have these dates

[image]

I think that the problem is that the `CDATE` is not working on `NULL` values which is normal and I have to find a way to convert only if not null, but I don't know how.
Anyone can help please ?

Comment: I can't see where you are converting the dates but `If Cell.Value <> vbNullString` would do it

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I am wondering if you really read my question...I am not looping through cells ! I am making an sql select, that's first...as for conversion, the CDATE is to convert etc....please check back what I wrote, anyway thanks for trying to help

Comment: Can you show the VBA code block to see how values are passed into SQL query? Also is the entire column of *ClipDate* formatted as Date?

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for trying to help. My data ClipDate column is not formatted), the vb code line that I use to create my condition is the following , 
`MySql = "CDATE([ClipDate]) BETWEEN " & QUO & CDate(Search.txtClipFrom.value) & QUO & " AND " & QUO & CDate(Search.txtClipTo.value) & QUO
`

Before this I add a where and the select of course...

and the QUO means a constant containing """" to add quotes
and the code that I provided above is the result of the Debug.print of my variable

I think what I need in my code is to tell it, don't convert NULL value into dates in select

Comment: It seems that I got it work by simply removing the CDATE from behind ClipDate, I will keep testing tomorrow to confirm that couldn't test yet on all cases, but these 2 seems to work 

`MySql = "[ClipDate] >= #" & CDate(Search.txtClipFrom.value) & "# AND [ClipDate] <= #" & CDate(Search.txtClipTo.value) & "#"`


`MySql = "[ClipDate] BETWEEN #" & CDate(Search.txtClipFrom.value) & "# AND #" & CDate(Search.txtClipTo.value) & "#"`

but still would like to know is there a way to say convert to date the clipdate if not null and don't covert if null ? in my sql ?

Comment: Please edit your post with code attempts and then delete these long comments which are difficult to read.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-2017) which is supported with ADO and allows for binding of VBA values to a prepared SQL query for maintainability and readability and avoidance of type enclosures like pound signs, `#`.

```vb
Sub RunSQL()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim m_Connection As Object, cmd As Object, rst As Object
    Dim sqlStr As String
    Const adCmdText = 1, adDate = 7, adParamInput = 1

    ' CONNECTION
    Set m_Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    m_Connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                      "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
                      ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    ' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH NO DATA BUT PLACE HOLDERS
    sqlStr = "SELECT [ListName] AS [List name]  " _
              & " FROM [Database$]" _
              & " WHERE CDATE([ClipDate]) BETWEEN ? AND ?"

    ' CONFIGURE ADO COMMAND
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = m_Connection
        .CommandText = sqlStr
        .CommandType = adCmdText

        ' BIND VALUES
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("fromdate", adDate, adParamInput, , _
                                            CDate(Search.txtClipFrom.value))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("todate", adDate, adParamInput, , _
                                            CDate(Search.txtClipTo.value))
    End With

    ' CREATE RECORDSET FROM COMMAND EXECUTION
    Set rst = cmd.Execute
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    rst.Close: m_Connection.Close

    MsgBox "Successfully completed!"

ExitHandle:
    Set cmd = Nothing: Set rst = Nothing: Set m_Connection = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try it and let you know what it gives but can you please explain to me the idea behind this solution ? and there is something that I am not really understanding, when I use the sql inside my excel, it's the MSAccess sql that I have to use , Or the standard SQL ?

Comment: The `?` is a standard placemarker for parameterization, compliant in any SQL dialect. Let me know if you have issues.

Comment: the ? is a simple question mark, nothing to have with the code itself...but why I am asking you that, it's that in my select I read that in msaccess you should use * to replace 1 or more caracters in a select query, but in sql it's % ... i tried in my code, the * didn't work and the % worked. Thus I said it seems that I should use SQL not access standards. But I can't find that logical because we are in Excel.  On the same time if i use Convert which is sql it doesn't work, if i use cdate, it works, so sometimes sql (%) and sometimes(cdate) access works I am not understanding why

Comment: The asterisk and percent are wildcard operators. I do not understand they are relevant here. No where here do you use `LIKE`. Please let me know if this solution does not work for you.

Comment: It's not related to the code here, it's a general question about should I use sql syntax or access syntax and the wildcards were an example to tell you why I am asking the question, it's not related to the code here itself

Comment: regarding your above solution, the "?" in your code will be automatically replaced by the parameters ? and in which order please ? I am talking here about the "?" in your code  : WHERE CDATE([ClipDate]) BETWEEN ? AND ?

Comment: No SQL dialect is the same including Access. It uses the ANSI-89 `*` wildcard for `LIKE` not the ANSI-92 `%` but it can with `ALIKE`. See [docs](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1). For params, values in `CreateParameter` lines are binded in corresponding order to `?`. Please test and see.

Comment: thanks a lot very interesting  information. do you have any tutorial (not only the doc above) ? I find what you provided me as information very usefull for futur projects, even if for the moment beeing the answer of Gustav (CVDate) seems to solve my problem, but your answer is very very interesting for every project as i see. thanks a lot

Comment: Understood. Access docs, tutorials, forums are abound online. Google/Bing are your friends! Remember SQL is an industry language and different RDBMS's (Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, etc.) all have their varied dialects. Do note: SQL parameterization is the preferred way and is used beyond VBA in other programming languages (e.g., Java, Python, PHP) interfacing with SQL. If your Excel app connects to an actual database, you never want to concatenate user input values to an SQL string (see the famous [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/))!

Comment: Thanks again, I will select gustave answer as selected one. Thus if someone else had same problem as me, it helps him to solve his problem and i will vote + to your answer and comments because it's really very helpfull thanks to both

Comment: can you please read the last comment I put on the answer of Gustave ? his solution is fine for not having a problem with null and bad values in database, but it's not picking up the good result, for example I put this : WHERE CVDate([ClipDate]) >= #12/12/2013# AND CVDate([ClipDate]) <= #01/09/2019#;
and I am getting wrong results, the ones that are in 2019 are not selected, i have in my database something like 12/03/2019, they are not selected

Comment: Curious, why did my answer not work? Did you not implement correctly? What were errors/undesired results? What happens when you format the entire column as *Date* type in Excel and save it before running?

Comment: not your answer didn't work, the one of CVDATE from gustave. it seems that to compare date I should convert my dates to mm/dd/yyyy to make them work instead of current one which is dd/mm/yyyy ? that's what I am reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819611/how-to-format-date-in-a-sql-query
I will give it a try, but why we are obliged to convert to mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: Please see full updated macro solution with error handling. It should compile in Excel. Be sure to add a blank sheet named `RESULTS`. I ran with day-first or month-first format for the date string inside `CDate()` in `CreateParameter` lines and both solutions worked exactly and perfectly on my end!

Comment: Your code give me an error : Invalid use of Null, error number : 2147467259 this is definatly because I don't have only dates in my field ClipDate....do you have any solution to say, select ...Where isdate(clipdate) ?

Comment: One perfect reason to underscore that [Excel is not a database](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+is+not+a+database) since databases assumes as does SQL: one data type per column (no mixed types). Consider a non-SQL solution for your needs. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Use *CVDate* - and the *ISO sequence* for the values:

```
SELECT [ListName] AS [List name] 
FROM [Database$] 
WHERE CVDate([ClipDate]) BETWEEN #2017/09/01# AND #2019/03/14#;
```

**Edit**. Filter out invalid date strings:

```
SELECT [ListName] AS [List name] 
FROM [Database$] 
WHERE 
    IsDate([ClipDate]) AND
    CVDate(IIf(IsDate([ClipDate]), [ClipDate], Null)) BETWEEN #2017/09/01# AND #2019/03/14#;
```

**Edit 2**: To split the dd/mm/yyyy formatted text dates:

```
WHERE 
    IsDate([ClipDate]) AND
    DateSerial(Mid([ClipDate], 7, 4), Mid([ClipDate], 4, 2), Mid([ClipDate], 1, 2)) BETWEEN #2017/09/01# AND #2019/03/14#;
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and let you know tomorrow, because the workbook is at work and i am now at home. Can you explain to me the difference between the CVDATE and the CDATE that I used ? the CVDATE won't cause error if the field contains null ?

Comment: Yes. _CVDate_ accepts _Null_, and returns _Null_ if so, thus returns a _Variant_ that matches the possible values of a _DateTime_ field.

Comment: It's true, CVDATE is not giving any error. what is strange is that microsoft suggest not to use it I don't know why, anyway I will pick your answer as used one because it solve the mentioned problem

Comment: It seems that I was wrong....I don't have anymore the problem of null, but result is not really right...i put from date 12/12/2013, to date 01/09/2019, and it's not giving me the right results, for example it's not selected the date that are : 12/03/2019..should I reopen a new question or there is a way to get more help here ?

Comment: Your dates probably represent 2013-12-12 and 2019-01-09, thus will exclude 2019-03-12. Use the ISO sequence as shown in my answer: 2019-09-01 for September 1st.

Comment: what do you mean by ISO SEQUENCE ? i used the exact where that you typed....in my dates format in the [clipdate] and the From, To fields, I type the dates with the format DD/MM/YYYY, but it seems based on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819611/how-to-format-date-in-a-sql-query that we have to convert the dates to mm/dd/yyyy to get right select ?

Comment: You didn't mention anything about a form. We have your SQL only, including the date values. Copy/paste that into a query and it will provide the expected result.

Comment: What Form ? I tried to add to your sql the format and now it works if I put something like : 
MySql = "CVDate([ClipDate]) BETWEEN #" & Format(CDate(Search.txtClipFrom.value), "YYYY-MM-DD") & "# AND #" & Format(CDate(Search.txtClipTo.value), "YYYY-MM-DD") & "#"

Comment: Study (insert `Debug.Print ..` in your code) the values of `Search.txtClipFrom.value` and `Format(CDate(Search.txtClipFrom.value), "YYYY-MM-DD")`.

Comment: I am getting a problem with the CVDATE if the data inside the database are not real dates. is there any way to tell, do the CVDate ONLY if ISDATE([ClipDate]) ?

Comment: Yes, see expanded answer, please.

Comment: I added the where isdate([ClipDate]) but still same error, and here is how looks like my where condition (i tried also with between i get same error but i prefere >= and <= on between) : WHERE IsDate([ClipDate]) AND CVDate([ClipDate]) >= #2010-10-10# AND CVDate([ClipDate]) <= #2024-10-10#;

Comment: Then you will have to include the error correction within CVDate. See edited answer, please. This works for me.

Comment: it's gonna drive me crazy..I tried your edited code, I have no more error, fine, but the select is giving 0 record !! while I do have dates in ClipDate that are between the selected dates !  My WHERE become like that but i go no results (which is wrong knowing that i have in the database dates like 30/04/2019, 12/03/2019,12/03/2019, 20/03/2019 ):   WHERE IsDate([ClipDate]) AND CVDate(IIF(IsDate([ClipDate]), [ClipDate], Null)) >= #2010-10-10# AND CVDate(IIF(IsDate([ClipDate]), [ClipDate], Null)) <= #2024-10-10#;

Comment: I aslo tried to format the clipdate to check but same result (no error but 0 record found)  WHERE IsDate([ClipDate]) AND CVDate(IIF(IsDate([ClipDate]), Format([ClipDate],"YYYY-MM-DD"), Null)) >= #2010-10-10# AND CVDate(IIF(IsDate([ClipDate]), Format([ClipDate],"YYYY-MM-DD"), Null)) <=
 #2024-10-10#;

Comment: You may have to use brute force and split the text dates into parts and convert these to date values. See _Edit 2_ in answer, please.

Comment: The Edit2, give back the error. That's really too much, can't understand at all why nothing works.  here is my clause : WHERE (IsDate([ClipDate])) AND (DateSerial(Mid([ClipDate], 7, 4), Mid([ClipDate], 4, 2), Mid([ClipDate], 1, 2)) >= #2010-10-10#) AND (DateSerial(Mid([ClipDate], 7, 4), Mid([ClipDate], 4, 2), Mi
d([ClipDate], 1, 2)) <= #2024-10-10#));

Comment: Can't tell. My Edit2 is tested here and runs ignoring totally invalid text dates.

Comment: It's not logical that your code doesn't work, but that's what happening unfortunatly, it's driving me crazy, I am wondering if there is something related to format or a kind of invisible caracters or specific caracter doing that