# How to work with dates in Excel VBA SQL. Trying to create a select statement where [orientation date] is greater than a chosen date variable

Tags: sql, excel, vba

The SQL select statement that I created in Excel VBA is not working properly with dates. I have tried putting the date as a variable and just entering not as a variable, also with # signs and not. The statement works in that it provides results, but the dates from the [Orientation Date] column are not filtered how I want. For instance, I set strCurrentDate365 to equal to 23 Oct 2023. Then in the SQL statement I want it to return records where the [Orientation Date] is greater than strCurrentDate365, but the results includes records with all dates, lesser and greater.

```
Sub employeeInquiry()

Dim strCurrentDate365 As Date
strCurrentDate365 = "23 Oct 2023"
strCurrentDate365 = Format(strCurrentDate365, "mm/dd/yyyy")

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

'********************* Annual Expirations *******************
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT [Employee ID#], [Employee Name], [Company], cdate([Orientation Date]) " & _
         "FROM [Training_Database$] " & _
         "WHERE [Employee Name] IS NOT NULL " & _
         "AND [Employee Name] <> 'blank space' " & _
         "AND [Employee Name] <> 'Employee Name' " & _
         "AND [Orientation Date] > #" & strCurrentDate365 & "# "

rs.Open strSQL, cn

'select and clear results sheet
Sheets("Inquiry_Results").Select
Cells.ClearContents

'row and column to insert
Dim r As Integer
r = 2
Dim c As Integer
c = 1

'insert result
Cells(r, c).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

**Test Table:**

| Employee ID# | Employee Name | Company | Orientation Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blank space | blank space | blank space | Lifetime |
| blank space | blank space | blank space | WFD |
| blank space | blank space | blank space | 5 hours |
| **Employee ID#** | **Employee Name** | **Company** | **Orientation Date** |
| 752856 | Smith, John | Waste LLC | 12/28/2023 |
| 685273 | Jones, Tracy | Paint & Co | 11/7/2023 |
| 385418 | Ramirez, Jen | Waste LLC | 12/23/2023 |
| 787233 | Johnson, Ted | Paint & Co | 10/7/2023 |
| 988534 | Smith, Jane | Waste LLC | 10/22/2023 |
| 438541 | Williams, Ken | PipeFab LLC | 11/18/2023 |

Comment: Things to try - Parameterised query and non-ambiguous (or less ambiguous) date format e.g. yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167367/error-in-excel-vba-with-sql-query-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the code will run into an error if you have "wrong" regional settings like I do

```
Dim strCurrentDate365 As Date
strCurrentDate365 = "23 Oct 2023"
strCurrentDate365 = Format(strCurrentDate365, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

I'd suggest to write it like that (I also removed the use of hungarian notation)

```
Dim currentDate365 As Date
currentDate365 = #10/23/2023#
```

It is also wrong to use CDATE in the SQL string as you did unless you indeed have a column with the title `cdate([Orientation Date]` what I think you do not have. You cannot convert a column to date in such a way.

The "trick" in this case is to use `CDbl` as  MS Office programmes (Excel & Access, for example) use doubles to store dates and times: `"AND [Orientation Date] > CDbl(currentDate365)"`

```
Sub employeeInquiry()

    Dim currentDate365 As Date
    ' Use a date, do not rely on implicit conversion
    currentDate365 = #10/23/2023#
    
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strCon As String
    
    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    '********************* Annual Expirations *******************
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    cn.Open strCon

    Dim strSQL As String
    ' Using cdate in the string does not make any sense
    strSQL = "SELECT [Employee ID#], [Employee Name], [Company], [Orientation Date] " & _
        "FROM [Training_Database$] " & _
        "WHERE [Employee Name] IS NOT NULL " & _
        "AND [Employee Name] <> 'blank space' " & _
        "AND [Employee Name] <> 'Employee Name' " & _
        "AND [Orientation Date] > " & CDbl(currentDate365)
        
    rs.Open strSQL, cn
    
    Sheets("Inquiry_Results").Cells.ClearContents

    'row and column to insert
    Dim r As Integer
    r = 2
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 1

    'insert result
    Sheets("Inquiry_Results").Cells(r, c).CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    cn.Close

End Sub
```

**Update:** One can avoid the trick with CDbl by using parameters

```
Sub employeeInquiry()

    Dim currentDate365 As Date
    ' Use a date, do not rely on implicit conversion
    currentDate365 = #10/23/2021#
    
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strCon As String
    
    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    '********************* Annual Expirations *******************
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    cn.Open strCon

    Dim Cm As ADODB.Command
    Dim Pm As ADODB.Parameter
    
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT [Employee ID#], [Employee Name], [Company], [Orientation Date] " & _
        "FROM [Training_Database$] " & _
        "WHERE [Employee Name] IS NOT NULL " & _
        "AND [Employee Name] <> 'blank space' " & _
        "AND [Employee Name] <> 'Employee Name' " & _
        "AND [Orientation Date] > ?;"
   
    Set Cm = New ADODB.Command
    With Cm
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .CommandType = adCmdText

        Set Pm = .CreateParameter("orientDate", adDate, adParamInput)
        Pm.Value = currentDate365
        .Parameters.Append Pm
        
        Set rs = .Execute
        
    End With
    

    Sheets("Inquiry_Results").Cells.ClearContents

    'row and column to insert
    Dim r As Integer
    r = 2
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 1

    'insert result
    Sheets("Inquiry_Results").Cells(r, c).CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide some additional assistance. I copy pasted exactly what you have here, and it gives: (Run-time error '-2147217904(80040e10)': No value given for one or more required parameters.) So I changed the final line of the select statement to:         "AND [Orientation Date] > " & CDbl(currentDate365) & "" so that it could recognize the variable. Then it gives another error of: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Sorry, I mand an error when copying the code. I fixed that and I updated it with another version how to do that which was mentioned in one of the comments.

Comment: So, the update, it ran but still returned records with a date less than 10/23/2023.

Comment: I would actually prefer to go the route of your first response if possible. There is still an error in it somewhere, the last line you have as { "AND [Orientation Date] " & > CDbl(currentDate365) } which is not working also.

Comment: You have to make sure that you have dates in the column [Orientation Date].

Comment: They are dates, formatted as short date cells. Only exception is the first 5 rows being text.

Comment: Difficult to tell without test data from your side. BTW, it is not a good idea to mix data type within one column. Secondly, only because it looks like a date it does not mean it is a date https://trumpexcel.com/vba-data-types-variables-constants/

Comment: What do you mean with _not working_ when referring to the first version of the code?

Comment: It won't let me add a picture to update, but it is giving a syntax error for the strSQL. I pretty sure it's how your last line is configured with the > and " signs

Comment: Yes, the `>` belongs "into" the string. Changed!

Comment: Added my test data. And now the first sub is working but it is returning a (data type mismatch in criteria expression.) error.

Comment: That's probably because you have text in the column [Orientation date].

Comment: Yep, runs as expected once I remove the first 5 rows that contain text. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way Excel sees cell contents and the way SQL, used from VBA to query Excel sheets, sees cell contents are not the same.

I took the data from the OPs question and pasted it into Excel as is and the result was the first four columns of the screenshot below.

[image]

In column four, "Orientation Date" only two of the pasted data values are recognised as dates on my UK format computer.

In column five, "Manually Typed UK Date" I have typed in the values from the previous column in valid UK date format.

In column six, "Copy Paste Values" I copied the previous column and pasted the values into the next column.

In column seven, I manually applied a Format to the column using (***select the six cells***), (***right click***), Format Cells > Number > Date > default type - this is UK format again. The cells contained a formula referencing the cell in column six. The warning is "The number format applied to this cell may be misleading"

In column eight I used the subroutine sbFixDates as follows -

```
Sub sbFixDates()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("H6:H11")
        c.Value = CDate(c.Value)
    Next
    Range("H6:H11").NumberFormatLocal = "m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End Sub
```

which was adapted slightly from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77771770/using-vba-formatcondition-to-highlight-dates-of-last-last-week) This forces a change to a date datatype and then applies a US format to the result. This on my computer set up for UK format dates.

In the next five columns I used this below helper function

```
Public Function fnVarTypeDesc(c As Range) As String
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function
' Constant           Value   Description
' vbEmpty            0       Empty (uninitialized)
' vbNull             1       Null (no valid data)
' vbInteger          2       Integer
' vbLong             3       Long integer
' vbSingle           4       Single-precision floating-point number
' vbDouble           5       Double-precision floating-point number
' vbCurrency         6       Currency value
' vbDate             7       Date value
' vbString           8       String
' vbObject           9       Object
' vbError            10      Error value
' vbBoolean          11      Boolean value
' vbVariant          12      Variant (used only with arrays of variants)
' vbDataObject       13      A data access object
' vbDecimal          14      Decimal value
' vbByte             17      Byte value
' vbLongLong         20      LongLong integer (valid on 64-bit platforms only)
' vbUserDefinedType  36      Variants that contain user-defined types
' vbArray            8192    Array (always added to another constant when returned by this function)

' vbEmpty            0       Empty (uninitialized)
 If VarType(c) = 0 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Empty (uninitialized)"
' vbNull             1       Null (no valid data)
 If VarType(c) = 1 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Null (no valid data)"
' vbInteger          2       Integer
 If VarType(c) = 2 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Integer"
' vbLong             3       Long integer
 If VarType(c) = 3 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Long integer"
' vbSingle           4       Single-precision floating-point number
 If VarType(c) = 4 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Single-precision floating-point number"
' vbDouble           5       Double-precision floating-point number
 If VarType(c) = 5 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Double-precision floating-point number"
' vbCurrency         6       Currency value
 If VarType(c) = 6 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Currency value"
' vbDate             7       Date value
 If VarType(c) = 7 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Date value"
' vbString           8       String
 If VarType(c) = 8 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "String"
' vbObject           9       Object
 If VarType(c) = 9 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Object"
' vbError            10      Error value
 If VarType(c) = 10 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Error value"
' vbBoolean          11      Boolean value
 If VarType(c) = 11 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Boolean value"
' vbVariant          12      Variant (used only with arrays of variants)
 If VarType(c) = 12 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Variant (used only with arrays of variants)"
' vbDataObject       13      A data access object
 If VarType(c) = 13 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "A data access object"
' vbDecimal          14      Decimal value
 If VarType(c) = 14 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Decimal value"
' vbByte             17      Byte value
 If VarType(c) = 17 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Byte value"
' vbLongLong         20      LongLong integer (valid on 64-bit platforms only)
 If VarType(c) = 20 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "LongLong integer (valid on 64-bit platforms only)"
' vbUserDefinedType  36      Variants that contain user-defined types
 If VarType(c) = 36 Then fnVarTypeDesc = "Variants that contain user-defined types"
' vbArray            8192    Array (always added to another constant when returned by this function)
' therefore VarType cannot return vbArray 8192 type
End Function
```

This function evaluated the datatype of the previous five columns. SQL when used from VBA uses this datatype. This adds a detailed explanation to [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686306/how-to-work-with-dates-in-excel-vba-sql-trying-to-create-a-select-statement-whe/77686931#77686931)