# Using VBA FormatCondition to Highlight Dates of Last Last Week

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using FormatConditions to highlight dates from a previous week, i.e. given a column of dates

```
Range("A2:A100").Select
With Selection
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTimePeriod, DateOperator:=xlLastWeek
.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color=RGB(0,255,0)
End With
```

To my understanding the DateOperator doesn't contain an option for dates from the week before last, e.g. there is no xlLastLastWeek, so my question is: how would I add a condition to highlight dates from the week before last?

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use VBA code to add a `between` FC (format condition)
- It does NOT automatically update as `lastweek` and `thisweek` FC when the OS system date changes.
- In the sample snippet, `Sunday` is considered the first day of the week; modify as needed.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [FormatConditions.Add method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim iWk As Long, sDay As Long, eDay As Long
    Dim oFC As FormatCondition
    iWk = VBA.Weekday(Date, firstdayofweek:=vbSunday)
    sDay = CLng(Date - iWk - 13)
    eDay = CLng(Date - iWk - 7)
    Set oFC = Range("A1:A200").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=" & sDay, Formula2:="=" & eDay)
    oFC.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

[image]

```vb
Sub fixDate()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A2:A100")
        c.Value = CDate(c.Value)
    Next
    Range("A2:A100").NumberFormatLocal = "m/d/yyyy hh:mm"
End Sub
```