# MsgBox if entered value in the cell is text

Tags: excel, vba, string, isnumeric

Dears,

Iam trying to create a Data validation in VBA.
Imagine I have a range of cells A1:A10 and I want a MsgBox to pop up if user enter text in one of the cells.

Iam trying below but does not work.

```
Sub test()

Dim rcell As Range
Set rcell = Range("A1:A10")

If IsEmpty(rcell) Or IsNumeric(rcell.Value) Then
Else
MsgBox "Error"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use the `Worksheet_Change` event handler, plus a loop. Btw this functionality already exists natively, under Data > Data Validation.

Comment: Consider this answer using a function to detect the datatype of the contents of a cell.  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686306/how-to-work-with-dates-in-excel-vba-sql-trying-to-create-a-select-statement-whe/77818664#77818664

Answer (score 0):

In the sheet module put the code like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10"))
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Application.CountIf(Target, "*") Then _
        MsgBox "Error"
End Sub
```

When you type or paste text into any of the cells `A1:A10` an error message appears.