# VBA - Text Variable transferred into number

Tags: excel, vba, text

in my VBA code I'm saving a variable as string because I need this to be open to text - numbers - date like numbers.
I then need to copy this into a table.

When copying the first time the variable stays in text but the second time it goes into number format if the text is something that resembles a date (e.g. "11-2023" gets copied into "45231").

It seems that my variable is saved as "45231" form this point forward.

How can I force the variable value to stay in "11-2023" style?

THX!

I try formatting the column as text, doesn't work.

Comment: `I try formatting the column as text` - do that before copying, not after.

Comment: ... e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "@"`.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686306/how-to-work-with-dates-in-excel-vba-sql-trying-to-create-a-select-statement-whe/77818664#77818664) about dates in Excel too.

Comment: Welcome Tommaso! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!