# VBA Code INSERT INTO - Preserving Date Format When Sending Data from One Workbook to Another

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Relative VBA noobie here, as an FYI.

I have a set of data that I am sending from one file into another by setting up a ADODB.Connection pathway and using the SQL Command INSERT INTO.

One of those columns I am sending to the other file is a timestamp, with the idea being we want to understand when the latest data was submitted into the other file and only use the data with the latest submission.

That all works fine, but the problem is when I attempt to bring the data back into the original document and use the latest timestamp as a criteria, it's not working because the date values are being submitted as General format. So when I try to do a SELECT MAX, it doesn't work.

How do I preserve the date format when pushing the data to ensure that when I try to use latest timestamp as a criteria, it works?

The query begins:

```vb
in_SQL_String = "Select [User_Inputs_TIME], [Other data column1], ..." 
"FROM [Database_File$] " & _
"WHERE [CDate ([User_Inputs_TIME]) = (SELECT MAX (CDate[User_Inputs_TIME])) FROM [Database_File$]...
```

I tried CDate, and that didn't work. Nor did manually updating the formatting in the file that I'm pushing the data to. There's some other criteria I have in the query as well, and the pull works only when I take out the timestamp criteria.

Comment: The way Excel treats dates is fairly unique, especially when you use SQL from VBA. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686306/how-to-work-with-dates-in-excel-vba-sql-trying-to-create-a-select-statement-whe/77818664#77818664)

Comment: Please show more of your VBA code, Basically you have to make sure that the date is in a configuration that SQL can understand and is not just formatted as a date by Excel.