# Insert current date and specific time format for Data Range only

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate an Excel file. Currently, we are provided with a workbook that contains information about clients. This is in a format that is not usable by our workload application.

To get the data transferred over to our workload application we have to modify the original (move columns, fill in blanks, remove rows if a specific cell has no data). I have managed to script all of that, but the one that is causing me issues is the time stamp for columns A and B.

In the upload template, I need to paste in the data from the original and then change the format of Column A to be "text" and then the date/time format of Date "mm/dd/yyyy 12:00" but only for the data range that has been pasted in.

Column B to be "text" and then the date/time format of Date "mm/dd/yyyy 12:00:00" but only for the data range that has been pasted in.

I have managed to set the format of the columns to be Text, and the data pasted in, but the date/time only shows a numerical value (i.e. 45365.31). And it also fills in the date/time for the entire columns (at most there are 40 - 50 entries every few days).

The code I have tried so far is:

```vb
' Set Column A and B with today's date format
For each cell in range(A:A)
    cell = (Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy 12:00"
next

For each cell in range(B:B)
    cell = (Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy 12:00:00"
next
```

And the latest one (Excel locked up on me with this one):

```vb
For Each rng In Sheets("Tracker").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)
    If rng.Value <> "" Then
        Columns("A:A").Value = Format(Date "mm/dd/yyyy 12:00")
    End If

    For Each rng In Sheets("Tracker").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)
        If rng.Value <> "" Then
            Columns("B:B").Value = Format(Date "mm/dd/yyyy 12:00:00")
        End If
```

What I was expecting/hoping for was Column A and Column B to look similar to:

Comment: Format the column to a date type, or use the column/range `NumberFormat` to do so. Also, you wrote "look similar to:*, but provided no example of how you want it to look. You may want to edit to do so.

Comment: `only for the data range that has been pasted in.` How to determine the `data range`?

Comment: Read this answer about how Excel handles dates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686306/how-to-work-with-dates-in-excel-vba-sql-trying-to-create-a-select-statement-whe/77818664#77818664

Comment: Welcome krhymer! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Answer (score 0):

Your two code snippets do not produce the expected results. They attempt to fill all cells in columns A and B.

- The first snippet is missing the Format function.
- The second snippet lacks the Next statement.

---

- Locate the last data row on Col I
- Search the blank cell(s) on Col A and Col B with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`, then fill with `Date`
- Apply date formatting on Col A and Col B

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.NumberFormat property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144167)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, visRng As Range, c As Range
    With Sheets("Tracker")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        Set c = .Range("A2:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.Value = Date
            .Columns("A").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
            .Columns("B").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```