# What is the way to use universal SQL date format in MS Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis

In SQL the universal date format is YYYYMMDD

For example. To search records greater than 15 Jan 2021 I write:

```
Where Datecol>='20210115'
```

This works irrespective of US or UK machine.

Is there an equivalent of this in the MS Access database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format date in a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819611/how-to-format-date-in-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access uses octothorpes and separators:

```
Where Datecol >= #2021/01/15#
```